# how to populate all * in input field and type on it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text/ textarea field with max size = "25" and want to ensure it has 25 '*' or something like that (a bullet) populated. When I click on it and start typing it should type on the *. Just like we have on SAP GUI when we are logging in.

any ideas?

```
  <textarea  onclick="typing()"/>
```

Comment: There is no input of type "textarea", you want "text" for a text field, or "password" for a password field which will hide the input with asterisks.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect textarea tag

Comment: You're looking for *[input masking](https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/)*. Consider doing some research on that (there are plugins that can help), and if you have a *specific* question, you can include your attempts and what you're stuck on. *"Any ideas?"* is *way* too vague of a question to ask, especially when you haven't shared any research or code that you yourself have already done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute `type="password"` to hide the input. You don't need any javascript or css to make this happen and it has had universal browser support for quite some time.

Comment: I do not want to use type="password" as it is autocomplete the value even when autocomplete is off